# Node promise chain seems to be broken at string-matching, how to resolve?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, promise

I've been working on the following code for awhile now. I'm fairly new to Promises and asynchronous code, but I've read some very handy posts here and elsewhere describing them in the process of creating the code below.

The purpose is to create a function to detect text in an article where the writers inserted link tags, and properly replace them as links to another article with the same name if they exist. In this case, the text tag link to another article called `articleName` would be written as `<<articleName>>` -- I know the style `<<texthere>>` can cause some issues, but the actual tags themselves can change. I just want the text replacement to properly return so I can pass the new string into the response to be rendered.

I am at a loss with what the issue is, here -- it just seems that at some point after `linkedArticle` is passed, the promise chain is broken. I'm thinking that using a regexp match (I've used string.js's `between` function as well, with the same result) does not work with `Promise.resolve()`. I've gotten output such as just a string of the `matchedArray` to `undefined`. I may be overdoing the `return` and the `Promise.resolve()`, I'm not sure.

I am using Node.js and Mongoose. I've played around using native promises, `async`, `string.js` and `underscore`. The code below uses async and string.js.

I've tidied up the code below as much as I can to post here. Apologies for the long argument passing in + tons of returns and resolves (it may very well be a reason for my problem?). It was one of the things I was doing to check where the chain could be breaking; I kept it for this post just to segregate things a bit to hopefully improve readability.

Article schema is straightforward with a string entry for an introduction, which is what I used just for testing purposes.

```
//Show article
var show = (req, res, next) => {
  let id = req.params.id;

  Article.findOne({_id : id}).populate('_author').then(function(article) {
    if (!article) return res.render('404');

    return Promise.resolve(replaceTextLinks(article.introduction)).then(function(text){
      console.log("Returned text is" + text)
    });


  });
}

var replaceTextLinks = (text) => {
  let regExp = /<<([a-zA-z0-9 ]+)>>/g;
  console.log("Initial passed in text is: " + text)
  return Promise.resolve(text.match(regExp)).then(function(matchArray){
    console.log("Matched array is: " + matchArray);
    async.each(matchArray, function(matchText){
      console.log("Matched Text is: " + matchText);
      return linkArticle(text, matchText);
    });
  }).catch(function(err){
    console.log("Error encountered: %s", err);
  });
}

var linkArticle = (text, matchText) => {
  let regExp = /([a-zA-Z]+)/g;
  return Promise.resolve(matchText.match(regExp)).then(function(linkedArticle){
    console.log("Linked Article is: " + linkedArticle);
    return Promise.resolve(matchArticle(text, matchText ,linkedArticle));
  })
}

var matchArticle = (text, matchText, linkedArticle) => {
  return Article.findOne({title:linkedArticle}).then(function(matchedArticle) {
    console.log("matchedArticle is: " + matchedArticle);
    if(matchedArticle) {
      return Promise.resolve(replaceTextWithArticle(text, matchText, matchedArticle, linkedArticle));
    }
  })
}

var replaceTextWithArticle = (text, matchText, matchedArticle, linkedArticle) => {
  console.log("Replacing initial text: " + text);
  replacedText = '<a href=' + '/articles/view/' + matchedArticle._id + ">" + linkedArticle + "</a>"
  return Promise.resolve(S(text).replaceAll(matchText, replacedText).s).then(function(newText){
    console.log("Replaced text is: " + newText);
    return Promise.resolve(newText);
  })
}
```

Below is the console output when I run 'show'. There is an article elsewhere in the Article collection called `Privacy`, which matches the tag passed in, `<<Privacy>>`. Returned text being undefined right after LinkedArticle on the console is telling me the hiccup is somewhere there, but I could be wrong. It is consistently so even with articles with three tags.

```
Initial passed in text is: This article contains a tag, <<Privacy>>.
Matched array is: <<Privacy>>
Matched Text is: <<Privacy>>
Linked Article is: Privacy
Returned text is undefined
matchedArticle is: { _id: 5909f3efe8d05c4e3827c4d1,
  title: 'Privacy',
  _author: 5909f3eee8d05c4e3827c4d0,
  category: 'Security',
  introduction: 'Type your article\'s introduction here...',
  contents: 'Type your article\'s content here...',
  conclusion: 'Type your article\'s conclusion here...',
  __v: 0,
  published: false }
Replacing initial text: This article contains a tag, <<Privacy>>.
Replaced text is: This article contains a tag, <a href=/articles/view/5909f3efe8d05c4e3827c4d1>Privacy</a>.
```

Thank you very much for any assistance you can offer; I'm just at a loss where the promise chain seems to be breaking itself.

Comment: What is `S(text).replaceAll`?

Comment: That's a function in stringjs; it replaces all text in `text` that matches `matchtext` with `replacedText`.

In this case it replaces `<<Privacy>>` with the `<a href...` within `This article contains a tag, <<Privacy>>.`

Comment: Mixing Promises with asyncjs is never a good idea - also, your code has about 7 more calls to `Promise.resolve` than required - for example `replaceTextLinks` returns a `Promise.resolve` that will result in that function returning a promise that resolves to undefined almost **immediately** because the `.then(function(matchArray){` function doesn't return anything at all (i.e. `undefined`)

Comment: @JaromandaX Appreciate the reply here and below. I admit I'm very new to promises - especially when mixing asynchronous calls and synchronous results - I've had the impression that all synchronous results needed a resolve to go with them. Understandably, this -was- overkill and demonstrates that the concept is still quite foreign to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you're over-using `Promise.resolve` - in fact, you don't need to use that **at all** in your code

Secondly, `Promise + async.js === nothing but trouble`

So, removing all the useless `Promise.resolve`, and replacing async.each with Promise.all and relying on the fact that `matchArticle` is the only function that NEEDS to return a Promise, which it does, because `.findOne` apparently does, your code can be greatly simplified - The code below doesn't use ALL the ES6 tweaks I could've added to your code, but I don't want the code in the answer to be beyond your abilities

```
const show = (req, res, next) => {
    const id = req.params.id;

    Article.findOne({_id: id}).populate('_author').then((article) => {
        if (!article) {
            return res.render('404');
        }
        return replaceTextLinks(article.introduction).then((text) => {
            console.log("Returned text is" + text)
        });
    });
}

const replaceTextLinks = (text) => 
    Promise.all(text.match(/<<([a-zA-z0-9 ]+)>>/g).map(matchText => linkArticle(text, matchText)));

const linkArticle = (text, matchText) => 
    matchArticle(text, matchText, matchText.match(/([a-zA-Z]+)/g));

const matchArticle = (text, matchText, linkedArticle) => {
    return Article.findOne({title:linkedArticle}).then(function(matchedArticle) {
        console.log("matchedArticle is: " + matchedArticle);
        if(matchedArticle) {
            return replaceTextWithArticle(text, matchText, matchedArticle, linkedArticle);
        }
    });
};

const replaceTextWithArticle = (text, matchText, matchedArticle, linkedArticle) => {
    console.log("Replacing initial text: " + text);
    replacedText = '<a href=' + '/articles/view/' + matchedArticle._id + ">" + linkedArticle + "</a>"
    return S(text).replaceAll(matchText, replacedText).s;
};
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed solution. I appreciate it! This did the trick.

One question, however - as I tried to edit my answer and compare with yours, one big thing that 'broke' the return (and gave me null results or warned me of uncaught promise errors) was the fact that my functions were defined with 
`var functionName = (args) => { stuff }`

But they function perfectly when I wrote them to be like yours `functionName = (arg) => stuff`. In particular, it was the `linkArticle` function.

Why is that the case? Why does the notation make most of the difference?

Comment: `functionName = (args) => { stuff }` - no implied return ... `functionName = (arg) => stuff` where stuff is a single statement, there's an implied return ... i.e. `functionName = (arg) => stuff` === `functionName = (arg) => { return stuff; }`